# Printing last entered element of linked list repeatedly

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list.The program will ask for a number until a negative number is entered while adding those numbers to the linked list.But when i try to print the linked list the last element entered into the linked list is printing repeatedly.If i enter the numbers 1,2,3 the number 3 will be printing repeatedly

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
int data;
struct node* next;
};
struct node* head;

void print(){
for(struct node* ptr = head;ptr!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next){
    printf("the num %d\n",ptr->data);
    }
}

int main(){
head = NULL;
struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
int i;
do{
    printf("enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    if(i<0)
        break;
    temp->data = i;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL){
        head = temp;
    }else{
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }

}while(i>=0);

print();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debugger................

Comment: linked list, ... again... exhausting.

Comment: Your linked list consists of the same node structure for each element of the list. You keep putting new values into the same structure. You need to allocate a new node for each list element.

Comment: I figured it out at the same time. But I had to look very hard at the code until it finally confessed...

Comment: @MartinJames in retrospect this is one of the not-so-bad linked list questions so far: understandable, almost [mcve], short, and with a description of the problem. Keeping that one as a duplicate target as well.

Comment: Check [This Demo](https://ideone.com/z6W7VV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

this line is done *outside* the loop, so the same memory cell is used for all your elements... move the allocation *inside* the loop.

```
do{
    printf("enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    if(i<0)
        break;
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = i;
    temp->next = NULL;
```